# Advanced Drive Services in Addons

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a Google Script that uses the Advanced Drive API service and am now looking to convert this script into an Add-on.

However the Drive API needs to be enabled manually by the user before using the service inside the Apps Script.

Is it possible to use the advanced APIs inside Apps Script. Thank you.

Comment: what you mean my needs to be enabled manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use advanced services in Add-ons. It only has to be enabled once by you before you publish your script to the Add-on store. All script requests using that advanced service will come out of the quota for the console project associated with your add-on.

Comment: From [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/#authorization): When a user installs an add-on, Apps Script scans the code to determine which built-in or advanced Google services it uses, then prompts the user to authorize access to their data.

Comment: Yes Advanced drive service will access the users drive, but the quota will come from the add-ons console project. You don't get a quota per user.  Hence you don't need to enable the drive api per user, only per project.